# Delicate git merge of current codebase

Tags: git, synchronization

I got in some weird issue here and before do any actions I would like to get some advices.

We have a legacy project that the company wants to add it to git. My colleague already added git repo and commit the legacy code into it. But I have doubts that it is not quite in sync with the code on the live system. As we plan to use git in future, now we need to add/sync the current code from live server, to the git repo with current code that is already on the repo. Live server is not handled by git so far. But will be, once we perform that sync. I need to make sure, that code from the live server will go on git, omitting any changed files that are already been added to git repo and will continue to work as before git. After then we will add that git to staging server, where we will sync with git and test and if all is OK - will just sync the live server.

Hope this scenario is explained well enough, but if not - please, let me know and I`ll shed more lights on it.

Thanks in advance.

Live server to continue to work with original code, while we get in sync the whole code base, spread  on several servers.

Comment: Can you add the following 2 clarifications: 1. is your current code versioned with another tool ? 2. if it is, do you want to port the existing history to git ? or are you ok with not keeping the full history ?

Comment: @LeGEC: No, there is no any version control at this moment. As for the history, I really do not care of any history at this moment as there is no any changes in the git`s current repo. It is on it`s initial commit. History will be build once we perform that sync and start working on it.  Damn legacy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to make sure, that code from the live server will go on git, omitting any changed files that are already been added to git repo and will continue to work as before git.

That means you need:

- to get a local copy of the live server current code
- to reset your Git repository to its first commit (before any changes)
- to add your server code to that Git repository, in a dedicated branch
- finally, to merge that branch to your current branch (which will preserve any recent change, but will update non-changed files with the server code from the dedicated branch)

That is:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git switch -c server_sync <your Initial commit before any changes>
git add --work-tree=/path/to/local/copy/of/server/codebase .
git commit -m "server sync"
git switch main
git merge server_sync
```

---

Actually, from [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75066835/delicate-git-merge-of-current-codebase/75066945?noredirect=1#comment132470537_75066945):

> We made our repo, with last stage code from vendor's repo and now I have to make sure it is the same as on the live server, prioritizing the code from the server

Then it is simpler: you don't need a dedicated branch:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git switch main
git add --work-tree=/path/to/local/copy/of/server/codebase .
git commit -m "server sync"
git push
```

Comment: Is there any specific "git init" that I have to perform, before start this scenario? As I said "Live server is not handled by git so far. ", so there is no any git there. Will "git init" harm something?!

Comment: "My colleague already added git repo and commit the legacy code into it. ": the `git init` was done at that step. Then, multiple commits were made and pushed ("omitting any changed files that are already been added to git repo")

Comment: Sorry, I really felt I didn't explain it right. The repo was made. It consist of the repo got from the vendor. It has some code that no one here knows what stage it is. I assume it is on some initial state. If any changes are made they are on the live server, which was supposed to be the same as in the vendor's git, but I cann't bet on that. So we made our repo, with last stage code from vendor's repo and now I have to make sure it is the same as on the live server, prioritizing the code from the server. I had that feeling the play is mostly with branches and merges, but wasn't really sure.

Comment: @ИванАлександров Then it is even simpler: take your Git repo as it is (initialiimport of vendor code), add a copy of the live server code as mention in the answer. The difference is: you don't even need a dedicated branch: you just add the live server code on top of your existing repository code.

Comment: That is what I'm not really sure how - git init, git add . , git commit...? I'm only a "master" of git clone and that is my best part :)

Comment: @ИванАлександров If you are cloning an existing repository, there is no need for `git init`. Only add, ocmmit and push.